# Double .htaccess rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to do a double redirect and can't get the logic right:

**1.** If the page exists, ignore all rules

**2.** If the page doesn't exist, add the .php extension (but hide it in the URL bar)

**3.** If the page doesn't exist and it doesn't exist with the .php extension redirect to a single page (query.php) and append what was typed into the url bar as a variable parameter (and hit it in the URL bar).

> **Example file structure:**

index.php
pricing.php
query.php

> **Example tests:**

```
[domain]/pricing.php   -> [domain]/pricing (showing the pricing.php page)
[domain]/pricing       -> [domain]/pricing (showing the pricing.php page)
[domain]/somethingelse -> [domain]/somethingelse (showing the query.php page with ?somethingelse appended)
```

> **Htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ query.php?$1 [L]
```

> **Actual tests:**

**Good**

```
[domain]/pricing.php -> [domain]/pricing (showing the pricing.php page)
[domain]/pricing     -> [domain]/pricing (showing the pricing.php page)
```

**Bad**

```
[domain]/somethingelse -> [domain]/somethingelse (showing the query.php page with ?somethingelse_php appended)
```

The .htaccess file I have above does everything I want it to except when I spit out the $_GET variable when redirected to query.php it shows "_php" appended. I'm assuming because of the earlier rule...

Comment: Rockett's answer is good. Here's the extra step to ensure / routes to index.php as well: Place at top of other rules:
# Re-route / to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following instead. These condition/rule-sets are specific to the requirements you have listed, and provide you with fine-grain control over what is served to the user.

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# Serve the requested file if it exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If not, then check if its .php equivalent exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.+)/?$ $1.php [L]

# Otherwise, send the request off to query.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)/?$ /query.php?$1 [L]
```

In terms of the last rule, requesting `/testing` should result in a dump of the following when using `var_sump($_GET)` in `query.php` if `/testing.php` doesn't exist:

```
array(1) { ["testing"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Comment: Thank you - this is correct based on my request and thus marked correct. I did not ask for it to make sure that [domain]/ displays the index page instead of the query page...I'll figure that part out.

Answer (score 0):

> Try the  following Rules

```
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.+)/?$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/query\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$    /query.php?$1 [L,R]
```